# How to get Workbook Name after opening the workbook using workbooks.open?

Tags: excel, vba

```
Workbooks.Open "C:\abc.xlsx"
Workbooks("abc").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:B7").Clear
```

In the above code I am opening the workbook  using `Workbooks.Open` in first line. In the second line I am accessing the opened workbook using the workbook name.

How can I access the opened workbook without the filename in second line?

(I want to create a function and I don't want to pass both the file paths and filenames separately)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an object of type Excel.Workbook and open the workbook into that.

Like so

```
Dim w as Excel.Workbook
set w= Workbooks.Open ("C:\abc.xlsx")
```

and then you can say

```
w.worksheets.add.....
```

etc

Answer (score 4):

You need to use references and reference the workbook and the sheet for example:

```
Option Explicit

Sub OpenWorkbook()

   Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet

   Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\abc.xlsx", UpdateLinks:=False, ReadOnly:=True)
   Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")

   ws.Range("A1:B7").ClearContents

End Sub
```

Note that the parameters on the openworkbook such as `Updatelinks`and `ReadOnly` can be modified to `True` or `False`as you need to.

Answer (score 1):

You can shorten your code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub OpenWb()

    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = Workbooks.Open("C:\abc.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1")

    With ws '<- Use With Statement to avoid sheet repetition
        .Range("A1:B7").ClearContents
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
Option Explicit
Sub TEST()
Dim WB As Workbook
Set WB = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\abc.xlsx")
For Each WB In Workbooks
    If WB.Name = "abc.xlsx" Then
        WB.Worksheets(Sheet1).Range("A1:B7").ClearContents
        Exit Sub
    End If
Next
End Sub
```